# Angular template variable not getting updated

Tags: angular

I am facing difficulty in populating channels field which is part of md-select, I am evaluating and populating channels array in preInit function after making a websocket call,

```
<bunch of imports>

@Component({
  selector : 'app-ipmi',
  template : `
  <md-select name="channel" placeholder="Channel" (change)="switchChannel()" options = "channels">
  </md-select>
  <entity-form [conf]="this"></entity-form>
  `,
  providers : [ TooltipsService ],
})
export class IPMIComponent {
  @Input('conf') conf: any;


<bunch of variable declarations>


  public channels = [];
  public fieldConfig: FieldConfig[] = [

    {
    ...
    },
    .....,

  ];

  constructor(...) {}

  preInit(entityEdit: any) {
    entityEdit.isNew = true;
    this.ws.call('ipmi.query', []).subscribe((res) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
        this.channels.push({label: res[i].channel, value: res[i].channel})
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<md-select>` should contain `<md-option>` elements, and to display options based on `channels` array, you can iterate through it using `*ngFor` directive, like `*ngFor="let channel of channels"`. So your HTML should be something like this:

```
<md-select name="channel" placeholder="Channel" (change)="switchChannel()">
  <md-option *ngFor="let channel of channels" [value]="channel.value">
    {{channel.label}}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```